# WordPress “wp-admin” redirecting to a user account login

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I’m getting a very strange error. When I try to log in to the back-end of WordPress at the address mysite.com/wp-admin, to access the back-end, I am automatically being redirected to mysite.com/login.php... as if I were trying to log into an account as a regular user or a customer.

I’m a novice with WordPress, and I can’t seem to figure this out. Please help.

I have a website which allows some of the users to post available jobs around the block and others apply through it.

Thank You

I'm not using any plugin to implement the front-end at all. 
I tried to login using the regular admin credentials and it didn't work.

A way to login the back-end so i can customize the site

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you have a theme redirect. Try logging into your site using the login page it should function the exact same way. If not try seeing if the theme has any documentation about its redirect. and if you are able to get to the admin section i personally like having ithemes installed which lets me set my own url for the backend. You can also try /wp-login.php as well.